# How to create date object and get timezone abbreviation from ISO 8601 date format string in node js

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

I want to convert `2021-11-05T08:41:37-05:00` string to something as `11-05-2021 8:41am EST` with time zone abbreviation at the end as `EST CST PST` etc

Is there is a way to capture timezone abbreviation from ISO String?

I have tried following option

```js
var d =new Date(Date.parse('2021-11-05T08:41:37-05:00'));
 

console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'US/Eastern' }))
```

which gives me string as `11/5/2021, 9:41:37 AM` but does not contain any zone abbreviation at the end.

Comment: There is no single canonical standard time zone abbreviations. "CST" can be Central Standard Time (what you probably mean) or China Standard Time (likely not what you mean) or Cuba Standard Time (also likely not).

Comment: And just the offset doesn't give you the time zone or the time zone abbreviation either. Multiple time zones can have the same offset at the same instant. So basically, the answer is "no, you can't do this".

Comment: @VLAZ & Jon skeet thanks for your response. This is the requirement in one of the project that end user should receive notification on delivery with timezone CST, EST etc. Delivery will be in CST, MST, EST & PST. No other time zone are in scope right now.